# How can I run a mutateFunction onClick in my jest test code and get its value?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, apollo-client

#### What I want to do

We have created hooks that communicate useMutation and switch the display when a button is clicked in a React component.

This test code is created using jest.

#### Occurring problems

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')]
```

#### Source code in question

```js
# Todo.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Todo = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState('')
  const [mutateFunction] = useMutation(CREATE_TOKEN);

  const changeTodo = async (agreement) => {
    const createTokenData = await mutateFunction();

    if (createTokenData.data?.token === null) {
      setToken('')      
      return;
    }
   
   setToken(createTokenData.data?.token)
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => changeTodo(true)}>
        Change Todo
      </button>
    </div>
  )
};
```

```js
# Todo.test.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Todo } from 'Todo'

jest.mock('@apollo/client');

describe('Click the button', () => {
    test('The value of token is null', async () => {
    const mocks = [
      {
        request: {
          query: CREATE_TOKEN,
        },
        result: {
          data: {
            createPcfToken: null
          },
        },
      },
    ];
    render(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
        <Todo />
      </MockedProvider>
    );
    const button = screen.getByRole('button');
    fireEvent.click(button);
  });
});
```

#### What we tried

I am creating　it while referring　to　the　apollo　official　website,　but　I　cannot　receive　data　from mutateFunction.

I have tried everything but it just fails. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Two mockImplementation solved the problem！

```js
const mocks = {
    {
        data: {
          token: null
        },
    };
}

const mockMutation = jest.fn()
(useMutation as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => [mockMutation]);
(mockMutation as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => mocks);
```